# 3-manifold theorem reference request or proof

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, manifolds, polyhedra

The following is a theorem of which I have great interest in but cannot find anything about on the internet,

> Every 3-manifold of finite volume comes from identifying sides of some polyhedron

I'm fairly certain that "identifying sides of some polyhedron" may be a simplification of the technical terminology. I believe it is just referring to gluing faces of polyhedron to form closed 3-manifolds. Such examples are given by the Seifert-Weber space, the Poincare homology sphere, the 3-dimensional real projective space, the $\frac{1}{2}$ twist cube space, etc. I'm assuming the proof is based off of [Moise's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moise%27s_theorem) and proceeds as follows,

> Let $M$ be an arbitrary closed 3-manifold. By Moise's theorem we have that $M$ can be tetrahedralized, so we let $T$ be the tetrahedralization of $M$ consisting of tetrahedrons $t_{1},...,t_{n}$. Pick an arbitrary tetrahedra $t_{1}$ of $T$ and proceed to glue $t_{2}$ to $t_{1}$, forming a new polyhedron $P_{2}$, and then glue $t_{3}$ to $P_{2}$ resulting in $P_{3}$, and so on. After all tetrahedra $t_{1},...,t_{n}$ have been glued, we have some resulting polyhedron $P_{n}$. From here, then somehow show that $P_{n}$ can be glued to $M$?

Any references to papers, expository writing, a proof of, or even the formal statement and name of this theorem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85956/3-manifold-theorem-reference-request-or-proof

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/85956/21564). I have replicated the accepted answer by Scott Carter below.

> I think the reference that you are looking for is  [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1912)  by Cannon, Floyd, and Parry.